# How to update info.plist with code?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am building an app in Xamarin, using Xamarin Studio / XCode / Visual Studio. I need to use the [Facebook SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookios) for the iOS project, but the instructions require adding the code shown on that link to `info.plist`. However, if I open info.plist in any of those IDEs, I get a window structured like a form to edit the file, so I can't add the code in as stated by the tutorial? Under Advanced, there is an option to add URL Types, but I am not sure what to put in here, or if this is the right option to use.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tired using a text editor to edit the info.plist file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, go to your Xcode project and find the `info.plist` file:

[image: Just open the folder and the file should be there]

You should see something like this:

[image: screenshot of the files on the left sidebar]

Then right click the file and choose **Open As**, and then **Source Code**:

[image: "Open As/Source Code" selected from the context menu]

And then it should allow you to add the Facebook code to your Info.plist file like this:

[image: screenshot of the source code]

Comment: Depending on the default text editor you use, you may not see exactly the same thing as in that last image.  Just be sure to add your FB entries in the same dictionary format/structure you already see in the file.

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin Studio, if you open Info.plist you should be able to switch to the "Source" tab.  From there you can either enter a predefined key, or "Custom Property" which can be set to any value.

Info.plist is a text file, so you could also edit it with any text editor outside of your IDE.

[image]