# How can I add the NSExtension & UNNotificationExtensionCategory keys to Info.plist?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, info.plist

How do I add `NSExtension` and notification-related values in Info.plist (refer to the image shown below)? Do I need to enter them manually? Adding a new row doesn't show any of these values in drop down list.

Do I need to enable anything else to see these values or am I missing something else?

[image: notification-related values in Info.plist]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you need to enter these names and set their types manually.

Just click on the + button which is present when you move your mouse over a row and edit the name of the new row to `NSExtension`/`UNNotificationExtensionCategory`. After that, select the correct type for each row by selecting it from the dropdown list next to the name field.

Alternatively, [open the property list file as source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34551947/3151675) and paste this to it:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
    <key>UNNotificationExtensionCategory</key>
    <string>category name</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```